# Thermalization in non-disordered systems

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, hawking-radiation, chaos-theory, ergodicity

The eigenstate thermalization hypothesis explains the mechanism of the thermalization of generic many-body quantum systems. The presence of disorder, on the other hand, provides an elegant example of many-body quantum properties that fail to thermalize and thus violates the ETH. I am wondering if there are quantum systems that violate ETH without disorder?